# Which facebook messenger event is triggered when a user tags an image with an emoji in his chat?

Tags: emoji, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook messenger now allows users to express their feeling with emojis directly on images sent in the chat.
Example :

[image]

I would like to capture the corresponding event in my facebook messenger bot but this user action does not seem to trigger any particular event. Am I missing something ?

My bot is subscribed to the messages and messaging_postbacks events : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference#setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature with reactions on messages is very new and, therefore, it has not been integrated in the Messenger API yet. However, they will probably add it in one of the next versions, as well as, the new polls system that is added in group chats.

Comment: As of today, looks like it's still not yet implemented in Messenger web hooks events : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events